# Some Application keeps creating folders

Tags: macos, finder, pdf, preview

I opened a write-protected and locked PDF-file with the Preview app. Originally it was located within a folder at the desktop.

Afterwards, I moved the file within its folder to a different location.

After some time, the containing folder reappeared at the desktop but without any content in it.

It has been some days since then and I rebooted several times. The folder just keeps reappearing. I delete it, it somehow gets recreated by some application after some minutes.

I even unlocked the PDF-file, moved it back and forth. I also deleted the folder with sudo in the terminal. It says that "staff" is the owner. But it keeps reapperaring.

What could I do? Can I see why the folder was created?

Comment: What is the name of the folder? Do you have iCloud sync for Documents and Desktop enabled?

Comment: iCloud for Desktop is not enabled. The name is just my previous chosen name where I stored the pdf-files, nothing system-related.

Comment: If you rename it once it got created, does an additional folder with the old name reappear as well after a while?

Comment: Yes, I renamed it and half an hour later, there appeared a new folder with the old name

Comment: You can try the following to find out which process recreates the folder: open Terminal, type `while :;do sudo lsof ~/Desktop/<folder name> 2>/dev/null; done` (replace `<folder name>` with the name of the folder that keeps reappearing) and press Enter (you will most probably need to type your password once). With a bit of luck this loop should print the process that creates the folder (you may need to delete the folder several times and wait for it to be recreated).

Comment: I tried the while command. However, it takes about half an hour, sometimes more until the folder appears. Unit then, this terminal command seems to use a lot of cpu or at least my fan gets very loud with this command. I also tried to look up the current applications in the activity monitor. But there are no applications with user staff (since the folder is owned by staff). I now hide the folder with "chflags hidden <folder>". Nevertheless, not an optimal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: It was the default download location of firefox. I changed it, deleted the folder, it never got recreated ever since.